# A metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit point is separable

Tags: real-analysis

Let X be a metric space in which every infinite subset has a limit point. Prove that X is separable.

*Hint*: Fix $\delta > 0,$ and pick $x_1 \in X$. Having chosen $x_1,...,x_j \in X$, choose $x_{j+1}$, if possible, so that $d(x_i, x_{j+1}) ≥ \delta$ for $i = 1, ..., j$. Show that this process must stop after finite number of steps, and that X can therefore be covered by finite many neighborhoods of radius $\delta$. Take $\delta = \frac{1}{n} (n = 1, 2, 3, ...)$, and consider the centers of the corresponding neighborhoods.
I'm following Baby Rudin and there is a part "centers of the corresponding neighborhoods" that I don't understand:

"Fix $p ∈ X$. Suppose that p is not in $A=\{x_1,...,x_k\}$. Note that $N_\frac{r}{2}(p)$ can be covered by finite many neighborhoods $N_s(x_1),...,N_s(x_k)$ of radius $s = 1/n$ where $n = [\frac{2}{r}] + 1$ and $x_i \in A$ for $i = 1,...,k$. Hence, $d(x_1,p) ≤ d(x_1,q)+d(q,p) ≤ \frac{r}{2}+s < r$ where $q ∈ N_{\frac{r}{2}}(p)\cap N_s(x_1)$. Therefore, $x_1 \in N_r(p)$ and $x_1= p$ since p is not in A. Hence,p is a limit point of A if p is not in A, that is, A is a countable dense subset, that is, X is separable." Can somebody explain the part with q, how did we get this inequality and then we got $x_1=p$,but $x_1\in A$ and $p \not \in A$. Isn't this a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

We have chosen $x_1,\dots,x_k$ such that $d(x_i,x_j) \ge 1/n$ for each $i\ne j$. Now, for any $p\in X$, it must be the case that $d(p,x_i) < 1/n$ for some $i = 1,\dots,k$. In other words, any other point we choose now cannot be farther than $1/n$ from all of the points $x_1,\dots,x_k$. In other words still, $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^k N_{1/n}(x_i)$. So if we choose $p\notin A$ (or $p\in X$ more generally), the neighborhood $N_{r/2}(p)$ is a subset of $X$, which is itself a subset of the (finite) union $\bigcup_{i=1}^k N_{1/n}(x_i)$. Hence, $N_{r/2}(p)$ can be covered by finitely many of the neighborhoods $N_{1/n}(x_i)$.

Comment: oh, got it, can you explain the next part with q, how did we get this inequality and then we got $x_1=p$,but $x_1\in A$ and $p \not \in A$. Isn't this a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, prove that if $X$ is not separable then $X$ has a sequence with no limit points, as follows:

For each $q\in \Bbb Q^+$ let $F_q$ be a maximal family of pairwise-disjoint open ball of radius $q.$

Maximal in that if $G$ is a family of pairwise-disjoint open balls of radius $q,$ and $F_q\subset G,$ then $G=F_q.$

Let $F_q=\{B_d(x_{j,q},q): j\in S_q\}$ where  $S_q$ is some  (arbitrary) index set, and with $B_d(x_{i,q},r) \cap B_d( x_{j,q},r)=\emptyset$  when $i\ne j. $

For every $x\in X$ there exists $j\in S_q$ such that $d(x,x_{j,q})\leq 2q.$ Otherwise $G=F\cup \{B_d(x,q)\}$ would contradict the maximality of $F_q.$

Let $C_q=\{x_{j,q}:j\in S_q\}.$ Let $D=\cup_{q\in \Bbb Q^+}C_q\,.$ Then $D$ is dense in $X.$ Because for any $x\in X$ and any $r>0,$ take $q\in \Bbb Q^+\cap (0, r/2),$ and take $x_{j,q}\in C_q$ such that  $d(x,x_{j,q})\leq 2q.$ Then $d(x,x_{j,q})<r.$

Now if X is NOT separable then then some $C_q$ is uncountable. Otherwise  the dense set $D=\cup_{q\in \Bbb Q^+}C_q$ would be a countable union of countable sets, which would make $D$ countable.

So for some $q_0\in \Bbb Q^+,$ the set $C_{q_0}=\{x_{j,q}:j\in S_{q_0}\}$ is uncountable. But for any unequal $i,j\in S_{q_0}$ we have $d(x_{i,q},x_{j,q})\geq q.$ So $C_{q_0}$ is an uncountable  closed discrete subspace of $X.$

So if $f:\Bbb N\to C_{q_0}$ is any injection then the sequence $(f(n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ has no limit points.

Comment: Every $C_q$ is a closed discrete subspace of $X$ (regardless of whether or not $X$ is separable). Perhaps  I should  have said that earlier in the proof than I did.